# debugfs lsdel prompt Filesystem not open,how to solve it

Tags: linux

I `rm` a directory `/var/lib/mysql` and I want to recover it.

I try `debugfs /var/lib` and command `lsdel` but:

```
lsdel: Filesystem not open
```

What does it mean? How to resolve it?